# pthread_create() как правильно работает?

Tags: c++, pthread, posix

У меня проблемы с использованием pthread_create если передавать в аргумент метод класса, потому что компилятор постоянно выдает ошибку:

```
cannot convert 'void* (Server::*)(void*)' to 'void* (*)(void*)' for argument '3' to 'int pthread_create(pthread_t*, const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)'    Server.cpp
```

у меня есть класс Server,у него есть приватный член `pthread_t receivingThread_;` публичная функция `void myFunc1()` и еще публичная функция `void* myFunc2(void *args)` которая возвращает 0.

Тут описание функции, где я делаю вызов pthread_create()

```
myFunc1(){
pthread_create(&receivingThread_,NULL,&Server::myFunc2,NULL);
}
```

Однако не работает, скорее всего где то обычная ошибка, но почитав другие вопросы, я не могу понять как мне исправить свою. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: метод класса принимает скрытый параметр `this`. Даже если вы приведете типы pthread_create не сможет этот this ему передать. может быть статический метод можно было бы использовать. Я пока вижу только костыль из обычной функции вне класса

Answer (score 0):

Вызвать нестатический член класса без указания объекта класса - нонсенс.

Если бы это был стандартный для C++ `std::thread`, то ему можно было бы передать первым параметром `this` и он бы радостно заработал - он достаточно умен для понимания таких вещей...

Но поскольку pthreads, по большому счету, C-библиотека, то нужен обходной путь - создание свободной функции, которая будет вызывать функцию-член для конкретного объекта.